# Need to include GPS data in a GIS system

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, google-maps, gps, telematics

I work for a small telematics company and we received a request from one of our clients about integrating their vehicle GPS locations to their ArcGIS system.

Our current system simply displays this location data on Google Maps through JavaScript.  I'm not really familiar with GIS, but I began doing some digging. From the best I could grasp, I need to write a web service that their GIS server can access in order to add it to the maps.

Our system uses a MySQL database that holds the data sent to it by the GPS devices. If a GIS map could derive the information straight from the database, that would be fine. The only real thing at that point would be how to define where the GIS server would look for the information. The data stored in the database is very expansive and contains a lot of information that is not pertinent to the map location.

- Is a route that can be taken?
- what's the best way to go about connecting a GIS server to retrieve
  information from our MySQL database?

Comment: this is very broad. more detail about the database; (oracle, mssql, ??) the format; (st_geom, esri egdb, sdo, ??) and how the client would use the "availability"; (download, map display, QA/QC,) might help to narrow it down. But it may not be a good fit for this forum.

Comment: Well, the location data is stored in mysql. They seem to want the data as a map display. As for the format, I'd need to ask. Mostly I've been dealing with people (management) who don't really know any technical specifications. But in reality, I really need a good starting point for me to do some research. I know I'm not going to get everything I need from a vague question like this.

Comment: No. Edit the original question with enough information that this question can meet our guidelines. Questions that ask for general guidance are not accepted. http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: for ArcGIS there is the Tracking Analyst http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006300000001000000

Comment: There are definitely ways of doing this without using extensions.  It depends on if you're grabbing location data from a database or reading it live via a NMEA stream.  Ultimately, it boils down to x/y points using the WGS84 coordinate system.  If you're pulling from a DB, most of the work is done already.  If you're reading a NMEA stream (or device SDK event), it takes a little more effort, but is still relatively simple.  If you **edit** your question with more info, you can get pointed in a better direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [GeoEvent extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/geoevent-extension) for ArcGIS,you can directly configure it without much coding.The description given says "*GeoEvent Extension includes connectors for common data streams including in-vehicle GPS devices, mobile devices, and social media providers. And if you need to use another type of data stream, you can find additional connectors online.*"

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a WFS service/and or WMS service, with software like GeoServer, MapServer, deegree, or ArcGIS server (others exist...) using your MySQL database as the datastore.

Then your client would be able to view a map, or access the raw (or sanitized version of the) data, in a number of ways including web browser and desktop GIS.